# Помогите выстроить селекторы

Tags: html, css

```
        <article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <strong>Vestibulum maximus nibh congue</strong>, congue dui a, auctor ex. Nullam risus orci, varius at sollicitudin vitae, placerat a risus. Etiam vel posuere mauris. Nullam sagittis eget arcu vitae eleifend. Curabitur auctor faucibus ornare. Sed et diam lorem. Vivamus eu commodo dolor. Nullam sed erat sit amet urna vehicula fringilla. Mauris pellentesque urna a sem pellentesque tempus. In et auctor erat. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla non enim ut ante ultricies euismod. Aliquam hendrerit, arcu nec vehicula facilisis, lorem est finibus metus, vitae gravida elit augue non quam. Cras pharetra, mi eu faucibus dictum, dui purus porta ante, vel convallis urna enim tempor massa.</p>
            <blockquote>
                <p>Donec nec arcu ac metus semper tempus. <strong>Donec elementum odio et purus</strong> luctus dignissim. Quisque non ante id urna elementum eleifend. Cras bibendum porta condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean at maximus elit, sed lacinia felis. Proin cursus vulputate nulla in faucibus. Quisque id purus non justo dapibus congue at a sem. Donec auctor pretium feugiat.</p>
                <p class="marked">Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum enim dui, laoreet eget varius quis, luctus vitae felis. Donec quis congue libero, suscipit vestibulum urna. <strong>Suspendisse sapien</strong> lacus, semper ut porttitor non, semper dignissim erat. Integer vitae rutrum velit. Donec gravida venenatis est maximus aliquet. Mauris pharetra nibh quis tristique venenatis. Vivamus rhoncus magna magna, nec elementum massa condimentum sit amet. Fusce dictum mollis tincidunt. Nam tortor elit, volutpat eget volutpat id, tristique vitae dui. Fusce sed ultrices mauris.</p>
            </blockquote>
        </article>
```

Как построить селектор к  strong во 2 по счету абзаце

, чтобы он не захватывал 3 по счету абзац с классом - marked и 1 по счету абзац?Я пробовал через nth но не выходит.

Comment: `blockquote p:first-child strong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
blockquote p:first-child strong {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<article>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <strong>Vestibulum maximus nibh congue</strong>, congue dui a, auctor ex. Nullam risus orci, varius at sollicitudin vitae, placerat a risus. Etiam vel posuere mauris. Nullam sagittis eget arcu vitae eleifend. Curabitur auctor faucibus ornare. Sed et diam lorem. Vivamus eu commodo dolor. Nullam sed erat sit amet urna vehicula fringilla. Mauris pellentesque urna a sem pellentesque tempus. In et auctor erat. Suspendisse potenti. Nulla non enim ut ante ultricies euismod. Aliquam hendrerit, arcu nec vehicula facilisis, lorem est finibus metus, vitae gravida elit augue non quam. Cras pharetra, mi eu faucibus dictum, dui purus porta ante, vel convallis urna enim tempor massa.</p>
            <blockquote>
                <p>Donec nec arcu ac metus semper tempus. <strong>Donec elementum odio et purus</strong> luctus dignissim. Quisque non ante id urna elementum eleifend. Cras bibendum porta condimentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean at maximus elit, sed lacinia felis. Proin cursus vulputate nulla in faucibus. Quisque id purus non justo dapibus congue at a sem. Donec auctor pretium feugiat.</p>
                <p class="marked">Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum enim dui, laoreet eget varius quis, luctus vitae felis. Donec quis congue libero, suscipit vestibulum urna. <strong>Suspendisse sapien</strong> lacus, semper ut porttitor non, semper dignissim erat. Integer vitae rutrum velit. Donec gravida venenatis est maximus aliquet. Mauris pharetra nibh quis tristique venenatis. Vivamus rhoncus magna magna, nec elementum massa condimentum sit amet. Fusce dictum mollis tincidunt. Nam tortor elit, volutpat eget volutpat id, tristique vitae dui. Fusce sed ultrices mauris.</p>
            </blockquote>
        </article>
```

Comment: Отредактировал. Сначала не увидел что надо стронг, а не весь абзац.